# Recurring error: Google Maps bundle missing from 'Copy Bundle Resources'

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

Every few days I get this build error:

`WARNING: Unable to find and load 'GoogleMaps.bundle' for Google Maps SDK for iOS. This may be a sign that you've forgotten to include a resources bundle in your 'Copy Bundle Resources' build phase.`

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources''`

Normally, to fix this error, I reinstall the `Google Maps SDK` Cocoa Pods per the most common instructions I found here for this error. But now that the error continues to resurface, I need to find a permanent fix (if there is one).

How should one properly add `GoogleMaps.bundle` to the `Copy Bundle Resources` when Google Maps was added via Cocoa Pods? I am using Xcode version 9.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue here. Here is how I solved it.

In XCode, in the project navigator, go to Pods > Pods > GoogleMaps > Maps > Frameworks

Right click on GoogleMaps.framework > Show in Finder

Expand GoogleMaps.framework > Resources

Drag the GoogleMaps.bundle into your XCode project navigator (under Frameworks) for a better readibility.

Click Finish to confirm the prompt that asks you to copy the item if needed.

Since, I have some CoreData warning in the console that I'm trying to see if it's important or not. But from what I read so far, it doesn't seem to.

Comment: 1. Drag the bundle file into the navigator at the same path Pods > Pods > GoogleMaps > Maps > Frameworks? 2. How does this change the process of updating the pods themselves, does this need to be done each time?

Comment: Apparently, it's interpreted differently by the compiler whether it's inside the project folder or the Pods folder. I can't tell you exactly why

Comment: Does this only happen with Google's pods? Because I've never experienced this with other pods. And can you point to any documentation so I can accept this answer?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find anything relevant in the Google Maps APIs website about this issue. And as it's a Google Maps SDK error, this message only appears with Google Maps SDK. But I personally had to do it as well for the TwitterKitResources.bundle recently that showed some kind of similar message.